# How to sum duplicates SQL/PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have some problem with how to build a query to sum all duplicates, in this query below I can count all occurrences.

---

```
SELECT COUNT (*) occurrences
FROM back.submission s
GROUP BY s.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
----------
|# |occurrences|
|1 |     9     |
|2 |     6     |
|3 |     5     |
|4 |     4     |
|5 |     4     |
|6 |     3     |
....
```

I would like to know how to sum all occurrences, i tried to put count inside SUM, but it doesn't work

Comment: So, you want to sum the occurences, you expected result is 9+6+5+... = 26? If not, what is your expected result?

Comment: What exactly do you have and what do you want? If at all you want to sum the duplicates, just multiply the number of occurrences to the duplicate value, eg if 9 is the number of occurrences for a value 10, the the sum is 90 ie 9*10. The re are 9 tens:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want another level of aggregation?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(occurrences) AS count_of_duplicates, SUM(occurrences) AS sum_of_duplicates
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT (*) occurrences
    FROM back.submission s
    GROUP BY s.name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT #,count(*) As Total FROM back.submission GROUP BY # HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: you are developer so it common sense  to fig it out

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE
As
(
Select [#],Count([*]) As Total From back.submission Group By [#]
)
select [#],Total From CTE Where Total>1
```